# How to browse months that have dates disabled?

Tags: react-datepicker

I'm working with this library: https://reactdatepicker.com/

I'm trying to make a "smart calendar" and for that i have just some available dates, in April, May and June. These dates are passed in prop `includeDates`.

I'm showing two months horizontally, and when i open calendar (pressing a button), displayed months are Feubrary and March (without available dates). So to select dates, i must browser to April.

The problem is this: Once April is displayed, i can't back to February. I can't back to months with disabled dates. I also can't see July following months.

There's some prop to fix this?

```
 <DatePicker
    disabledKeyboardNavigation
    inline
    selectsRange
    showDisabledMonthNavigation
    endDate={endDate}
    highlightDates={includeDates}
    includeDates={includeDates}
    minDate={new Date()}
    monthsShown={isMobile ? 1 : 2}
    renderDayContents={renderDayContents}
    selected={startDate}
    startDate={startDate}
    onChange={onChange}
  >
<DatePicker
```

I would like to navigate between months, even if there's no available dates.